# How to calculate displacement of an image with cross correlation in R?

Tags: r

I am comparing two satellite images (one optical and one SAR) and I want to determine the displacement between them. Both images have a spatial resolution of 30m. I would like to analyze the displacement in pixels (e.g., greater than half a pixel = 15m). I found a code and adapted it to my data. The script generates a cross-correlation image, but I don't understand what I have to do to generate a graphic where I can see the displacement in pixels (i.e., in meters). For example, if there are displacements greater than 15m, etc.
These are the images I am analyzing.

[Here my images: first optical and then SAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l00HJ.png)

Plese I need a help!! :)

```
## read my images with raster 
f1 <- as.matrix(readPNG("optical.png", package="png"))
f2 <- as.matrix(readPNG("sar.png", package="png"))  
## take the fft of the first  frame
F1 <- fft(f1)
## take the Conjugate fft of the second frame
noise.b <- runif(length(f2),min(range(f2)),max(range(f2)))
f2 <- noise.b+f2
F2.c <- Conj(fft(f2))

## calculate the cross power spectrum according to the wiki article
R <- (F1*F2.c)/abs(F1*F2.c)
## take the inverse fft of R
r <- fft(R,inv=TRUE)/length(R)
## because the zero valued imaginary numbers are not needed
r <- Re(r)
## show the normalized cross-correlation
image(r)
## find the max in the cross correlation matrix, or the phase shift -
## between the two images
min.err <- which(r==max(r),arr.ind=TRUE)
shift <- (dim(f1)+3)/2-min.err
```

Here's the result of the cross-correlation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lboE1.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to make it a self-contained simple example. That is, do not refer to files in your code --- as we do not have these --- unless the files ship with R.

Comment: Hello Robert, thank you very much for the suggestion. I just edited my post, could you help me please?